# Close button not fully showing in IE8 on Fancybox pop up

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

I am cross browser testing my development website.

In IE8 (tested via IE Tester software), when you launch a fancybox pop up, the close button in the top right is trimmed. I've tried setting overflow:visible on loads of fancybox divs but with no joy.

The gallery is at the bottom of this page: dev.enterf1.com/british-grand-prix.php

Hope some one can help. I bloody hate annoying things like this!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce this emulating IE8 on a Windows 7 machine.

[image]

Comment: Interesting! My friend in IE8 sent me a screen shot of the same problem. Probably not Windows 7, but I don't see how OS would make a difference. Hmm...

Comment: It could possibly be IE Tester or my emulation. I am not sure if either one is as accurate as actually just using IE8. It could also be the OS. Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764530/windows-7-rendering-web-pages-differently-than-xp-or-vista

Comment: Have him Press F12 (Developer Tools in Settings) in IE, he is likely in compatibility mode.  or IE7 mode

Comment: I tried it in my XP machine downstairs and it wasn't in any comparability mode. I tried every single combo of browser and standard settings!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Upgrading to the latest jQuery and fancybox version solved it. Must have been a few potential gremlins in the old code.

Cheers for your help all!